# from symfony 2.3.5 to symfony 2.3.6

Tags: linux, symfony, project, upgrade, composer-php

I am developing a project and I want to keep my code up to date with the latest stable versions of Symfony, now they have released the new stable version 2.3.6, and when I try to upgrade I receive the following error.

```
php composer.phar update
Loading composer repositories with package information



  [ErrorException]     
  Undefined offset: 3  



update [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--lock] [--no-plugins] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--with-dependencies] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [packages1] ... [packagesN]
```

Comment: That really looks like a software error in Composer. You should create an issue on their Github page. Probably  @Seldaek monitors this tag on SO, too, but in this case you should add more info: Which version of Composer are you using? And what is in your `composer.json`?

Comment: @Sven pretty much covered the problem but have you tried updating composer: `php composer.phar --self-update`?

Comment: I will try to update composer on Monday, but I have already installed the newest version from the website... Thank you guys.